# SELinux: AIDE Trying to Access SSSD Socket

Tags: selinux, aide

I'm getting SELinux denials indicating that `/usr/sbin/aide` is trying to access a socket used by SSSD: the socket path is `/var/lib/sss/pipes/nss`. Here is the relevant text from sealert:

```
Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:aide_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
Target Context                system_u:object_r:sssd_var_lib_t:s0
Target Objects                (null) [ sock_file ]
Source                        aide
Source Path                   /usr/sbin/aide

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1560503762.699:28324): avc:  denied  { write } for  
pid=37019 comm="aide" name="nss" dev=dm-3 ino=262366 
scontext=system_u:system_r:aide_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 
tcontext=system_u:object_r:sssd_var_lib_t:s0 tclass=sock_file


type=AVC msg=audit(1560503762.699:28324): avc:  denied  { connectto } for  
pid=37019 comm="aide" path="/var/lib/sss/pipes/nss" 
scontext=system_u:system_r:aide_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 
tcontext=system_u:system_r:sssd_t:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1560503762.699:28324): arch=x86_64 syscall=connect 
success=yes exit=0 a0=7 a1=7ffe5f7f2ea0 a2=6e a3=7ffe5f7f2b30 items=1 
ppid=37017 pid=37019 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 
fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=324 comm=aide exe=/usr/sbin/aide 
subj=system_u:system_r:aide_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)

type=PATH msg=audit(1560503762.699:28324): item=0 name=(null) inode=262366 
dev=fd:03 mode=0140666 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 
obj=system_u:object_r:sssd_var_lib_t:s0 nametype=NORMAL
```

I can modify the context to allow this, but I don't want to do that without knowing why AIDE would try to access a socket created by the SSSD service.

Answer (score 1):

The socket is [sssd's NSS responder](https://docs.pagure.org/SSSD.sssd/design_pages/not_root_sssd.html), which [is intended to use UNIX sockets](https://jhrozek.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/anatomy-of-sssd-user-lookup/). Because it is the auth daemon, presumably this relates to some libc NSS lookup of the passwd or groups databases.

It is reasonable for file integrity check software to look up user names. Please file a bug with your distro (I would guess Fedora or RHEL?) so they ship policy to allow this.

Comment: I have filed a ticket here: https://github.com/aide/aide/issues/46